# How does Djoser JWT login flow works

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

So I've been trying to use Djoser JWT and I don't know how to login in it. As far as I know you create a request with your login credentials to this url `/jwt/create/` and get the `access` and `refresh` token and maybe get the user object from `/users/me/`. This is where I got stuck, where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly understood the first step of the process. Basically, you can now:

1. Add the `access token` in the header of your next requests.

This will transparently authenticate the user thanks to the Simple JWT plugin and you will be able to access him with the usual `request.user` in the views.

2. Refresh the `access token` each time you get a 401 response.

The `access token` is supposed to be short-living for security concerns and a 401 response from the server indicates that the one your are using is expired. So you have to get a new one by sending the `refresh token` to the `token/refresh/` API and, then, make your request again.

You can read [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/12/19/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework.html) if you need more detailed explanations about this process or JWT.

Comment: So if I make a get request to the backend I'll do `Authorization: JWT ${access}` to the header and I can finally do `request.user` to get the user?

Comment: @Melly If you set your Authorization header this way, you just have to check if you set the `'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES'` to `('JWT')` in your SIMPLE_JWT settings. But then, yes, you can just do a `request.user` in the Django view handling your get request.